# How can I set a variable for all theme templates?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to set few global variables which I need to be available in all my theme's Twig templates in Drupal 8.

[Drupal 7 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) mentions preprocess function:

> themeName_preprocess
>   This one is named after the theme itself. Applies to all hooks.

So I added the function below to my `themename.theme` file, but the variables aren't set.

```
function themename_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = $variables['base_path'] . $variables['directory'];
  $variables['theme_path'] = $theme_path;
  $variables['images_path'] = $theme_path . "/images/";
  $variables['templates_path'] = $theme_path . "/templates/";
}
```

When instead of defining `themename_preprocess` I define `themename_preprocess_page` (below) the variables are properly defined and available in `page.html.twig` template. I also tried defining [`template_preprocess()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/8.3.x), but got error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare template_preprocess() (previously declared in /home/robert/programming/dns-drupal/core/includes/theme.inc:1202)`.

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = $variables['base_path'] . $variables['directory'];
  $variables['theme_path'] = $theme_path;
  $variables['images_path'] = $theme_path . "/images/";
  $variables['templates_path'] = $theme_path . "/templates/";
}
```

But I want the variables to be available in **all** templates instead of only `page.html.twig`. How can I do that?

Comment: `hook_preprocess` hasn't gone anywhere, that should work. Have you rebuilt cache?

Comment: @Clive: Yeah, it works after rebuilding the cache. Thanks! Only weird that `themename_preprocess_page()` was working without rebuilding the cache. That was totally misleading - I was sure that `themename_preprocess()` is simply not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

use hook_preprocess in a custom module, then it will available in all the themes.

for example here I set a `activeLang` and it will be available in all themes and pages

```
/**
 * @param $variables pass active lang everywhere
 */
function YOURMODULE NAME_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $interfaceLang = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage()
    ->getId();
  $contentLang = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)
    ->getId();
  $variables["activeLang"] = $contentLang ?? $interfaceLang;
}
```